Are contiguous objects contiguous in virtual memory or physical?
More or less what the title says.
Suppose we have a sequential container like vector in c++ that will store data contiguously.
When we say that the data is stored contiguously do we mean that it's contiguous in virtual memory or physical memory as well?
My understanding is that pages in virtual are mapped to page frames in physical memory so when we pull a cache line in the same virtual page it's likely to be in the same physical page as well so it's pulled with one memory access. Is that correct to say?
But when the vector spans more than one virtual page then there's no guarantee than those pages will map to physical pages that are contiguous in memory? Except maybe if we do reserve()?

As you correctly noticed, it is contiguous in virtual memory. Pages can and are mapped arbitrarily (at least from user's perspective). Calling reserve() doesn't change anything and is irrelevant. Also, since you have almost no control over that process (of assigning physical memory to virtual), you should not bother with that detail. It isn't really important.

The addresses within the vector must be contiguous in the address space that the program lives, because the program is expecting pointer addressing arithmetic to be mathematical.  On a machine using virtual memory, the program's address space is virtual memory — the program never sees physical pages or physical addresses, so it doesn't matter if physical pages are discontiguous relative to the virtual addresses.

Thank you both for taking the time to comment. I don't want to know because I am trying to do something programmatically with that information. I am mostly curious to know what happens to better understand what benefits caching would have and have a better understanding in general.

@codefast actually you cannot retrieve this information at all, unless you are writing a software that operates in kernel mode. But noone would run such software on their machine, so its pointless.

In essence, only the kernel's memory management system knows about the distinction between physical memory pages and virtual memory pages. For all the rest of the system and in particular user-space applications, the only memory the can know about is virtual memory.
When we say that objects are stored contiguously in memory, that always refers to virtual memory. We cannot know if the memory management also stores contiguous pages of virtual memory contiguously in physical memory.
But, it also doesn't matter what the memory manager does with the physical memory. If a virtual memory page is already mapped to physical memory, translating from virtual address to physical address takes (near) constant time and is not affected by physical pages being contiguous.
Also, loading the data from physical memory into the cache is not dependent on the organization of the physical memory. The access time for each memory page is the same.

My understanding is that pages in virtual are mapped to page frames in physical memory so when we pull a cache line in the same virtual page it's likely to be in the same physical page as well so it's pulled with one memory access. Is that correct to say?

Yes, that is correct. If you pull a second (or third, ...) cache line from the same virtual page, that page is likely to be mapped to a physical page frame already and the cache line can be loaded with a single memory access.
That single memory access is because the physical page frame is present, not because of objects being contiguous.
If you go to a new virtual page, it is possible that it is not yet backed by a physical page (the memory contents can be swapped out). In that case, the loading takes longer, because a physical page frame needs to be freed up (its contents swapped out) and the virtual frame needs to be swapped in.

Re your last 2 paragraphs: There is also an intermediate point, where a page is mapped to memory, but the mapping isn't cached in the TLB, so multiple references to main memory are needed, even though the page itself doesn't need to be swapped in.
